# Joining certain lines of text together before modifying them

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, regular-expression

I have a cricket commentary like -

```
0.3
Richardson to RG Sharma, 2 runs, gentle, non-swinging length ball on off, Rohit seeks to pick it up. Hit high on the bat and spooned over the returning Mitch Marsh at midwicket
0.4
Richardson to RG Sharma, 1 run, banged in short, controlled pull to long leg
```

What I want to do is join the `n.n` lines with the following lines, replacing newlines with spaces. Then, I want to delete everything from the second comma to the end on each line, so the output from the input above should be:

```
0.3 Richardson to RG Sharma, 2 runs
0.4 Richardson to RG Sharma, 1 run
```

---

-- Edit --
I used [0-9]"\n"[A-Z] to match the newline but I have trouble reproducing the exact number and character that was matched. Also for deleting everything after 2 commas, I tried parameter expansion but I could only get it to work for deleting after a single comma.

Comment: Show us what you tried. How do you expect us to point out where you went wrong without that?

Comment: I used [0-9]"\n"[A-Z] but I have trouble reproducing the exact number and character that was matched.
Also for deleting everything after 2 commas, I tried parameter expansion but I could only get it to work for deleting after a single comma.

Comment: What is your expected output? Its hard to understand what you have said in words..

Comment: Wow, @Michael Homer It does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -ne '/^[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-6]/ { N; s/\n/ /; s/^\([^,]*,[^,]*\),.*$/\1/; p; }' < data
```

This processes a file called `data`, suppressing printing unless asked for ([`-n`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_04)) and executing the sed program in quotes.

That program selects lines starting with one or more digits, a `.`, and a digit 0-6, and then runs the part in `{}` for those lines. The [`N` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-N-_0028append-Next-line_0029-command-155) reads the next line in as well, with a newline in between. The first `s///` replaces that newline with a space.

The second matches the new single line up to the second comma and replaces the whole line with just that first part. It captures a `\(` group `\)` with some string of non-comma characters, a comma, and some further string of non-comma characters, all followed by a comma and any text `.*` to the end of the line `$`.

The final [`p` prints](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-p-_0028print_0029-command-95) out the resulting line. All other lines of input are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution in AWK:

```
awk -v FS="," '/^[0-9]/{line=$0;getline; line=line" "$1", "$2 ;print line}' file
```